# Pass information from a webpage to another ASP.NET page inside an iFrame

Tags: asp.net, .net, jsf, web

I have a webpage in a WebLogic application server (JSF). Inside that page I have an iFrame which displays an ASP.NET page (with a code-behind dll). Users are authenticated in the JSF page and I want to, somehow, pass the username of the user to the ASPX page inside the iFrame.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest (but maybe not secure) way to achieve this is using QueryString.

An example for processing the QueryString in the ASP.Net side

- [Passing variables between pages using QueryString](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString).

From the JSF side, you can pass the parameter like this

```
<h:outputLink value="aspNetPage.aspx" target="iFrameName">
    <h:outputText value="Load asp.net page" />
    <f:param name="username" value="#{sessionScope['username']}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

JSF code based from: [JSF 2 Link, CommandLink And OutputLink Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-link-commandlink-and-outputlink-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You could write it to a session/cookie and read it from within the IFrame page.
Or you could use the DB route, depends on how you would like to implement it.